# Change information in a dialog box from another dialog box in WindowsBuilder?

Tags: java, eclipse, windowsbuilder

In windowsbuilder, I would like to change information from a seperate window, more specifically a table, from my main window. Is it possible to use my information from one seperate window to change it in another box?
Basically, take information from here:
[image]

And put it into this table:
[image]

Is it possible? If so, how? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible - but not in Windows Builder.

Create an object which will hold the information from the first window and pass the information from the window to the object. Next, pass the object to the second window (how you do this will depend on how you've configured your window objects). Finally, populate the table with the information from the object.

As far as I know, there is no direct way to do this in Windows Builder, although the above method will work fine provided you can pass objects from the first window to the second.